How to pass query parameter to Google strategy passport nestJs
Ok, so I am trying to pass a query parameter from my mobile app as /auth/google?purpose=addPlatform to my backend so that I can do stuff with that. Right now is not picking up the parameter. I am using a nestJs backend with passport and strategy assport-google-oauth20.
Below is my code, any thoughts?
Mobile makes call to /auth/google?purpose=addPlatform
This is my backend code:
dir `/auth/google

  @Get('google')
  @UseGuards(GoogleOAuthGuard)
  async googleAuth() {
    // Initiates Google OAuth login
  }

Google Strategy
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.GOOLGE_REDIRECT,
      scope: ['email', 'profile', ],
      accessType: 'offline',  // <---- Important!

    });
  }

  async validate(
    req: Request, // Add explicit type for req here
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
    console.log('accessToken', accessToken);
    console.log('refreshToken', refreshToken);
    const user = {
      email: emails[0].value,
      firstName: name.givenName,
      lastName: name.familyName,
      picture: photos[0].value,
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
    };
    done(null, user);
  }

Google Guard
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class GoogleOAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('google') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      accessType: 'offline',
    });
  }
}

